# Where does _original_ come from in my setter method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am looking at a crash log for my objective-c code.

It says -[MyClass _original_setMyVariable:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

What I'm curious about is, where did the `_original_` come from and what does it mean?

Comment: Can you include the rest of the crash log? My guess would be KVO name mangling.

Comment: It's a dynamic method wrapper around your method or property.  Basically the system creates special methods to keep track of stuff that is important to iOS, but invisible to you.

Comment: Yup -- that'd be a KVO wrapped method.